# Drawing a graph for n→n+1, n→ a⋅n mod m in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I have a newbie question. I would like to use `TikZ` to draw a graph with vertices `0,..,m-1` in a circle, and edges `n → n+1 mod m`, `n → a⋅n mod m`, where `m=19`, `a=5`, say.

The following attempt almost works - however, the arrows land at the wrong place (always at the rightmost point of the circle around a node):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \R {60}
\def \r {9}
\def \radius {\R mm}
\tikzmath{
  \m = 19; \a = 5;
  \margin = 2*atan(\r/(4*\R));
  \mm = \m - 1;
}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\mm}
{
  \node[draw, circle,minimum size=\r mm] (v_\n) at ({90-360/\m * \n}:\radius) {$\n$};
  \draw[->, >=latex, ] ({90-(360/\m * \n+\margin)}:\radius) 
    arc ({90-(360/\m * \n+\margin)}:{90-(360/\m * (\n+1)-\margin)}:\radius);
}

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,color=red]
\foreach \n in {1,...,\mm}
{
  \tikzmath{\ntimes = Mod(\n*\a,\m);}      
  \draw (v_\n) edge (v_\ntimes);         
}
\path (v_0) edge [loop above] (v_0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

(I know I should also make short edges bend.)

The following code does not compile at all:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \R {60}
    \def \r {9}
    \def \radius {\R mm}
    \tikzmath{
      \m = 19; \a = 5;
      \margin = 2*atan(\r/(4*\R));
      \mm = \m - 1;
    }
    \graph[clockwise, radius=6cm] {subgraph C_n [n=\m, name=A]};
    \foreach \n in {1,...,\mm} {
        \tikzmath{\ntimes = Mod(\n*\a,\m); \np = Mod(\n+1,\m);}      
        \draw (A \n) -- (A \ntimes);
        \draw (A \n) -- (A \np);
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the message: "! Package pgf Error: No shape named A 0 is known."

What is the matter in each case?

Comment: Please, extend your codes fragment to complete document. Also make it compilable: they have undefined commands like `tikzmath` ...

Comment: I guess it's the old problem that `\n` is a decimal number, so you get e.g. `1.0`, not `1`. As a result you end up drawing lines to the `0` anchor of the nodes, i.e. the `east` anchor. Edit: also `\ntimes` is a decimal, try `int(Mod(...))`

Comment: It would seem \n is not a decimal number, but \ntimes is.

Comment: All right, that seems to work. Out of curiosity, why does the second version (using the graphs package) not compile?

Comment: The nodes are named `A 1` through `A 19`, when \n = 18, \np becomes Mod(18+1,19) = 0, so you're trying to draw a line to a non-existent node (`A 0`).

Comment: Related: [TikZ.net: Times Tables and Mandelbrot](https://tikz.net/times-tables-and-mandelbrot/)

Answer (score 4):

As Torbjørn T. also noticed in the comments (before me it seems...), the problem is that `Mod` returns numbers like 1.0 so you are drawing nodes to the point at angle zero. I'd also drop the `scope` environment and, instead, use

```
[evaluate=\n as \na using {int(Mod(\n*\a,\m))}]]
```

(and `\tikzset`) to produce:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,math,positioning}

\def \R {60}
\def \r {9}
\def \radius {\R mm}
\tikzset{
myedge/.style={->, >=latex, shorten >=1pt, color=red}
}

\newcommand\macircle[2]{% m=#1, a=#2
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
      \margin = 2*atan(\r/(4*\R));
      \mm = #1 - 1;
    }
    \foreach \n in {0,...,\mm}
    {
      \node[draw=blue, circle,minimum size=\r mm] (v\n) at ({90-360/#1 * \n}:\radius) {$\n$};
      \draw[->, >=latex, ] ({90-(360/#1 * \n+\margin)}:\radius)
        arc ({90-(360/#1 * \n+\margin)}:{90-(360/#1 * (\n+1)-\margin)}:\radius);
    }

    \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \na using {int(Mod(\n*#2,#1))}] in {1,...,\mm}
    {
        \draw[myedge] (v\n) -- (v\na);
    }
    \path[myedge] (v0) edge [loop above] (v0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\macircle{19}{5}
\macircle{17}{6}

\end{document}
```

I have created your general macro and tweaked things a little.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the advantage of using evaluate rather than tikzmath?

Comment: @HAHelfgott None that I know of, except that it sometimes means that yo  do not need to load the `math` library. Rather it is a question of aesthetics. Arguably `\tizmath` is more explicit but I prefer to use `evaluate`. I guess what I wrote above is misleading as it is the use of `\tikzset` makes the scope unnecessary not the use of `evaluate`.

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of @Andrew answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=red,-{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3]}, semithick},
every loop/.style = {draw=red,-{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3]}, semithick}
                        ] 

\foreach \i in {0,...,18}
{
  \node (v\i) [circle, draw, minimum size=9mm] at ({90-\i*360/19}:6) {\i};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\margin}{atan(9/120)}
  \path[every edge]
    ({90+\i*360/19+\margin}:6) arc ({90+\i*360/19+\margin}:{90+(\i+1)*360/19-\margin}:6);
}
\foreach \n in {1,...,18}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nn}{int(Mod(\n*5,19))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(abs(\nn-\n))}
    \ifnum\j<3
        \pgfmathsign{\nn-\n}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
            \path (v\n) edge[bend right] (v\nn);
        \else
            \path (v\n) edge[bend  left] (v\nn);
        \fi
    \else
        \path (v\n)  edge[blue] (v\nn);
    \fi
}
\path (v0)  edge [loop above] ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]